# How to make more menu bar?

Tags: python, tkinter

This is what I have so far, it worked perfectly:

```
menu = Menu(self.master)

self.master.config(menu=menu)

file = Menu(menu, tearoff=0)

file.add_command(label='New')

file.add_command(label='Exit', command=self.client_exit)

menu.add_cascade(label='File', menu=file)

edit = Menu(menu, tearoff=0)

edit.add_command(label='Show Image', command=self.showImg)

edit.add_command(label='Show Text', command=self.showTxt)

menu.add_cascade(label='Edit', menu=edit)
```

but, when I tried to add a new menu bar with this code;

```
help = Menu(menu, tearoff=0)

help.add_command(label="About")

menu.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=help)
```

It gave me errors.

Comment: What errors ? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Under help = Menu(menu, tearoff=0), it says name error: name 'menu' is not defined... if i removed entirely of the new code my entire program works fine

Comment: Did you put the two code blocks in different functions?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not quite sure what you meant, but here is my full code: https://imgur.com/a/uAzcz57

Comment: I have tested your code and it works.

Comment: Any ideas why I couldn't? This is weird

Comment: can you show me your full code when you entered?

Comment: See [`here`](https://pastebin.com/vei6fFFz).